# Should Varnish hit when passed an unmatching ETag or an earlier modified date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, caching, reverse-proxy, varnish

We are currently spiking a Varnish implementation to see if it would be appropriate to sit in front of our Rails application.

We want Varnish to cache the results of an API call and only hit the application when the client's ETag doesn't match the one stored in Varnish or the client's modified date is before Varnish's.

So far, I have not seen Varnish take these values into account.

We only get cache hits when the secondary requests are within the max age.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior, Varnish does not currently revalidated cached content.

There is some experimental work to do what you want, which may or may not end up in Varnish 4.0 (in a few months).

In the meantime what you can do is set an artificially short TTL, and set a `grace` time equivalent to your desired TTL. With that configuration, when a request comes in Varnish will send an IMS request to the backend (as long as the cached entry has an ETag of course, otherwise it will be a plain request).

The side effect is that Varnish will also send the cached entry if the backend is down or returns 500—this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Uhm, did you edit the question or did I misunderstand it and reply something else entirely? :/

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is set the hash() function to use the etag provided.

This means that the first request for an object (no etag provided from client) will get the object itself.

Any subsequent request, or any request that provides the header for etag, will get either an object or the 304.